# Multiple Authentication Routes in Node

Tags: node.js, jwt, passport.js

I'm new to Node / Passport / JWT Auth, etc.

I'm trying to setup a website with multiple authenticated routes; one for users (ie. /account), and one for administrative purpose (ie. /admin).

In my routes file, I'm using:

```
app.get('/account', passport.authorize('jwt', {session: false}), (req, res, next) => { ... })
```

In my passport strategy I'm using:

```
ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme("jwt");
```

Should I just setup multiple schemes with different names, one for "account" and one for "admin"?

Does anyone have an example I can refer to that demonstrates a multi-level authentication schema?

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar to this before. What I finally ended up doing was just creating two different endpoints in express, each of which used passport.authorize as middleware, but had different callback functions. It worked like a charm.

Comment: I'd rather not author two separate websites if possible.. Is there no way to do this with multiple express routes? (ie. /account, /admin)

Comment: I never said anything about two websites. I said two endpoints in express.